# Can anyone tell me why I am having error in validating my xml against my xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Can anyone tell me why I am having error in validating my xml against my xsd?
This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=person.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Lecturer>
<Name>John</Name>
<Surname>Smith</Surname>
</Lecturer>
</Person>
```

This is my xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Lecturer">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing preventing your XML from being valid against your XSD is the omission of a quote around the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=person.xsd"` attribute value.

Here is your corrected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="person.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Lecturer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Surname>Smith</Surname>
  </Lecturer>
</Person>
```

Comment: I've confirmed that the shown, corrected XML is valid against the XSD in your question.   You'll have to be more specific than "it still doesn't work," if you'd like further help.  For example, providing the exact error message you're receiving would be more specific.  Thank you.

Comment: thanks man
My codes are working on my friends laptops but not working on mine.

Comment: Strange.  XML and XSD do not usually suffer from portability issues that would result in success on one machine and failure on another.  If you want to pursue, post here, or perhaps in a new question, the exact error message that you're seeing on your machine and whether it's with the exact XML and XSD shown in your question.